# нужна помощь с написанием программы на СИ

Tags: c

нужна помощь с написанием программы на СИ : нужно написать программу, принимающую на вход 2 неповторяющихся массива. программа должна объединять их в один

Comment: Где то, что ВЫ сделали? В чём именно проблема? Тому, кто ничего не сделал, можно помочь только и дальше ничего не делать...

Comment: К [фрилансерам](http://bit.ly/37fS3gS)... Здесь *помогают*, а не делают за вас. "Я делал такую задачу, сделал вот это, а вот тут не совсем ясно" - это совсем другое дело. Только "сделал вот это" не должно состоять из одной строки с `int main()` :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Принимаете 2 массива
2. Выделяете память размером длина_первого_массива + длина_второго_массива
3. Заполняете новый массив сначала элементами первого массива, потом второго